# How to make my own custom controls to appear in the toolbox panel in visual studio

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I am wondering how to make my own customer UI controls to appear in the toolbox panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DLL is not in the same solution, you need to add it by the following steps
1) Right click on the toolbox panel.
2) Select "Choose Items..."
3) Click Browse button and select your own assembly.